# Не меняется цвет приложения

Tags: java, android, android-resources, android-themes

При установки кастомной темы `setTheme()` почему-то  меняется только цвет `ColorPrimaryDark` .
Вот сама тема

```
<style name="Red" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ca3030</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" >#a42525</item>
</style>
```

Тему меняю из собственного класса `ThemeUtils`
Вот сам класс

```
package alphacorp.com.touristapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class ThemeUtils{
    private static int sTheme;

    public final static int FIRE_BRICK = 0;
    public final static int DODGER_BLUE = 1;

    public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {
        sTheme = theme;
        activity.finish();
        activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
        activity.overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                android.R.anim.fade_out);
    }

    public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
        switch (sTheme) {
            default:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                break;
            case R.id.red:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Red);
                break;
            case R.id.vk:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Vk);
                break;
            case R.id.green:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Green1);
                ;break;
            case R.id.pink1:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Pink);
                ;break;
            case R.id.orange:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Orange);
                ;break;
            case R.id.black:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Black);
            case R.id.green2:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Green2);
            case R.id.blue:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Blue2);
            case R.id.pink2:
                activity.setTheme(R.style.Pink2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `android:colorPrimary` требует, чтобы версия API была 21 и выше. На андроиде какой версии вы смотрите?

Comment: Я использую версия 7

Comment: Тема ThemeOverlay обычно используется для тулбаров, если у вас тема для активити или для application, то родительскую нужно указать Theme.AppCompat или Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: не получается ваш вариеант

Comment: Дополните вопрос, если вы кастомно вызываете setTheme из кода, то где это делаете? (приведите пример кода)

Comment: onActivityCreateSetTheme() вызываете до super.onCreate() или после?

Comment: @Vadik . После.

Comment: Проверил на своем устройстве, у меня не применяется цвет `android:colorPrimary`, но с `colorPrimary` всё ок (в отличие от colorPrimaryDark — он работает в двух вариантах). Проверьте ещё раз. Ну и setTheme вообще рекомендуют выставлять до super.onCreate(). Пока у меня идей больше нет.

Comment: А можно-ли как нибудь программно изменить эти дурацкие цвета ColorPrimary и ColorPrimaryDark

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81866/discussion-between-ilhom4ik-and-vadik).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте без префикса `android:`, а также если это тема задается для активити, то в качестве родительской темы нужно указать `Theme.AppCompat` (либо `Theme.AppCompat.Light` для светлой темы):

```
<style name="Red" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#ca3030</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#a42525</item>
</style>
```

Также имейте ввиду, что если выставляете setTheme() динамически из кода, то лучше это делать до вызова super.onCreate() в активити.

А также: возможно, что у вас у тулбара заданы собственные стили, из-за чего вы не видите изменений.

Comment: не получается, на этот раз цвет статусбара также не изменился